# In node_module Illegal 'use strict' directive in function with non-simple parameter list

Tags: reactjs, build, vite

I have currently finished migrating over my CRA application into a Vite environment. All test and functionality is working great.

However, when running `vite build` or `npm run build` I get the following error from a `node_module` which is a sub-dependency:

```js
[commonjs--resolver] Illegal 'use strict' directive in function with non-simple parameter list (11:2) 

 9:  * Date: 2023-05-11T18:29Z
10:  */
11: ( function( {}, factory ) {
      ^
12:
13:   "use strict";
error during build:
SyntaxError: Illegal 'use strict' directive in function with non-simple parameter list (11:2)
```

Any help on this? I have forced an upgrade in my package json with resolution, but still nothing.

Regards, :)

Comment: So the only fix was to remove the library. Unfortunately that required a major refactor in the component that uses the above.